# Assembly (TASM): print the sum of certain bits in bytes

Tags: assembly, buffer, offset, x86-16, tasm

My goal is to print the sum of every byte's 0th and 3rd bit. This is my code so far:

```
printLine macro line
    mov ah, 09
    mov dx, offset line
    int 21h
endm
;-----------------------------
readLine macro buffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset buffer
    int 21h
endm
;-----------------------------
getByteBitSum macro theByte
    mov al, byte ptr theByte
    mov cl, byte ptr theByte
    shr al, 3
    and al, 01
    and cl, 01
    add al, cl
endm
;-----------------------------
;-----------------------------
;-----------------------------
.model small
    ASSUME CS:code, DS:data, SS:stack
;-----------------------------
data segment para public 'DATA'
    message_1:
        db 'Enter a line'

    newLine:
        db 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'

    message_2:
        db 'You entered ',0Dh, 0Ah, '$'

    dataBuffer:
        db 20, 00, 20 dup (00)
data ends
;-----------------------------
code segment para public 'CODE'
    start:

    mov ax, seg data
    mov ds, ax

    printLine message_1

    readLine dataBuffer
    printLine newLine

    printLine message_2
    printLine newLine

    mov bx, 0000
    mov bl, byte ptr[dataBuffer + 1]
    mov word ptr [dataBuffer + bx + 3], 240Ah

    printLine dataBuffer + 2
    printLine newLine

    getByteBitSum [dataBuffer + 2]
    printLine newLine

    getByteBitSum [dataBuffer + 3]
    printLine newLine

    getByteBitSum [dataBuffer + 4]
    printLine newLine

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
code ends
;-----------------------------
stack seg para stack 'STACK'
    dw 400h dup ('**')
stack ends
;-----------------------------
    end start
```

The error I get is :

> GETBYTEBITSUM (1) Need right square bracket
>   GETBYTEBITSUM (2) Need right square bracket
>   GETBYTEBITSUM (1) Need right square bracket
>   GETBYTEBITSUM (2) Need right square bracket

My guess is that I don't really understand how `buffer` and its offset does work. If my conjecture is right, could anyone explain in short using this example what is happening with it?

BTW: As of right now I am only trying to print the first 3 bytes, not the whole input line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> getByteBitSum [dataBuffer + 2]
> ```

The macro expansion has difficulties with the embedded space characters!
Solve it by writing:

```
getByteBitSum [dataBuffer+2]   ;No more embedded spaces!
```

Comment: *printLine dataBuffer + 2* Beware of the same problem here! This time the compiler won't give an error, because without the * + 2* the macro expansion is also fine. The output of the program on the other hand will be faulty.